# How do I find ten biggest contours?

Tags: python, opencv, find, contour, area

I'm new to OpenCV and I don't understand deeply what I'm doing.
I'm looking for ten biggest light polluted areas in a photo of the dark side of the Earth.
After I've found the contours of every light polluted area, how do I create a variable with ten biggest contours?
I've tried

```
biggest_contours=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
for enum,contour in enumerate(contours):
    for item in biggest_contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(contours[enum])>cv2.contourArea(contours[item]):
            biggest_contours[item]=enum
```

but it returns "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: You have that error because `tuple` is immutable in Python, you can't change it once it's created, use list instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort the contours by their area and keep the last 10?

```
largest_contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-10:]
```

Comment: I've just tried what u proposed and when i try to use
cv2.drawContours(image_contours,largest_contours,-1,(255,255,0),1) the contours are not there

Comment: Difficult to know without more code, try `cv2.drawContours(image_contours, largest_contours, 0, (255,255,255,255), -1)`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hKmjVM3c
this is the code that I'm using and for some reason it doesn't display sorted contours

Comment: also when I use contours and not largest_contours everything works fine

Comment: That is odd, I use this myself so know it works. Depending on the opencv version, the return is different `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours()` but as it works with `contours` it should have failed before. `print len(largest_contours)` should give you `10`

Comment: yeah len(largest_contours) is 10 also printing each contour area looks fine